# my all updatepanels gets updated together javascript error

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am using this function to call textchanged function on keypress, problem is
it calls email.textchanged function but even if keypressed on ny textbox even if I name something like   `$($('#abcd')[0]).keypress(function ()` it calls same function

please suggest something

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var hTimeOut = null;`enter code here`
                $($('#email')[0]).keypress(function () {
                    if (hTimeOut)
                        clearTimeout(hTimeOut);
                    hTimeOut = setTimeout(function () { $($("#email")[0]).change(); }, 200);
```

my aspx code goes like this
*

```
<td>

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">


<ContentTemplate>



    <asp:TextBox ID="email1" runat="server" Height="52px" Width="200px"  AutoCompleteType="Email" 
        AutoPostBack="true" onfocus="this.value=this.value" class="email" 

          style="border-width:0; outline:none; border-style:none; border:none;  vertical-align:middle"
        BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" 
        CssClass="stext" MaxLength="100" ></asp:TextBox>



    <asp:panel ID="p1"  runat="server" >
        <div ID="UserAvailability" runat="server" >
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="images/spinner.gif" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </asp:panel>
           <ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender ID="PopupControlExtender2" 
        runat="server" TargetControlID="email1"
        BalloonPopupControlID="P1" Position="TopRight" BalloonStyle="Cloud"
        BalloonSize="small"     UseShadow="false" DisplayOnClick="true"   
        DisplayOnFocus="true" CacheDynamicResults="True" 
         />


        <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wm1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="email1"
WatermarkText="Email"
WatermarkCssClass="stext" />

 </ContentTemplate>

          <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="email1" EventName="TextChanged" />
          </Triggers>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>


   </td>

  <td> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanssel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">



<ContentTemplate>




    <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Height="52px" Width="200px" style="border-width:0; outline:none; border-style:none; border:none;  vertical-align:middle"             BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None"  AutoPostBack="true"            CssClass="stext"></asp:TextBox>

         <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wm2" runat="server"
TargetControlID="username"
WatermarkText="Username"
WatermarkCssClass="stext" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="username" EventName="TextChanged" />
      </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </td>
<td>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="images/su.gif" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>*

                }
            );

</script>
```

Comment: The question does not really make sense, could you re-phrase? By the way, why would you do `$($("#email")[0])`? It's pointless, you are selecting element with id "email" (`$('#email')`), extracting the dom element (`[O]`) and re-making a jquery object...

Comment: my textboxes has watermark extender and baloonpopup extender so i dont know waht exactly causing this cus this two extender also has similar functions like onfocus

Comment: Didier G. well actully i dont know exactly why i am using this script but only this one is  working to call  textchanged function on keypress event i found it on one stackoverflow's answer

Comment: Yuriy Rozhovetskiy

you are right but your script doesnt work it doesnt fire any postback and my script fires postback but it updates all the updatepanels thats what the problem is

Comment: Suggested script works well for me with your markup only with change `email` to `email1`. Just ensure that second UpdatePanel also updated with `<%= DateTime.Now %>` block in each UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to raise postback against textbox on keydown after 200 ms of inactivity. If it's right then you may use script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hTimeOut = null;

    $(function () {
        $("#<%= email.ClientID %>").live("keypress", function () {
            clearTimeout(hTimeOut);
            var textBox = this;
            hTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                $(textBox).change();
            }, 200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yuriy Rozhovetskiy you are right but your script doesnt work it doesnt fire any postback and my script fires postback but it updates all the updatepanels thats what the problem is

Comment: Do you know how to make this java script precise about keys? i mean no function should be called for arrow , tab etc keys